What is the first FPS game to use different ammo types for the same gun?
I was wondering, which was the first first-person shooter game to use different ammo types for the same gun? E.g., the shotgun in Turok 2 (1998) can use normal shotgun shells and explosive ones...

You're not allowing Tank FPS, are you? Not that I'm expecting any answers from that time, but just to narrow the years we're looking at. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_shooter#Origins:_1970s%E2%80%931980s

@Malady Technically, Tank would be more of a SIM than a FPS. I don't really care about the time, I just love FPSs and I was playing Turok 2 remastered last night, and I was trying to remember if before Turok 2 there was a game were you are able to use the same gun with different ammo types. In newer "games" there is Project Brutality which uses a grenade launcher and 6 different grande types, or the shotgun that has the buckshot, the slugs, and the dragon breath ammunition...

1993's ''Pathways into Darkness'' as reported by Giant Bomb:

In the case of the M-79 and the AK-47, it is also possible to switch to a different ammo type
[...]
M-79 Grenade Launcher:
40mm Fragmentation Cartridge - Does area-of-effect damage [...] within its range.
40mm HE Cartridge - [...] single-target damage.
40mm Projectile Cartridge - Causes damage to Greater Nightmares.
AK-47:
Normal Magazine - Does base damage to a target.
SABOT Magazine - Also inflicts base damage [...] harms Greater Nightmares as well.
HE Magazine - [...] greater damage than other types, [...] not affect Greater Nightmares.


I should have thought of PID, I +1 here and remove my own answer as this one is now both inclusive of my own and superior in all respects.

@WilliamWalkerIII - Well, now it doesn't mention your answer because it doesn't make sense, but thanks for the support and presumed upvote!
